# Setting environment variables based on passing Require directive

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

I finally succeed on configuring Apache as a SPNEGO reverse proxy for my app, and I'm using the `AUTHORIZE_SAMACCOUNTNAME`, `AUTHORIZE_CN` and `AUTHORIZE_MAIL` to figure out some information about the logged in user. But this is only the first step.

Currently, I'm using a generic rule like `Require ldap-group cn=General Group,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com`, but what I really need are multiple rules, one for each group. i.e.

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ldap-group cn=Regular Users,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com
    Require ldap-group cn=Managers,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com
    Require ldap-group cn=Admins,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com
</RequireAny>
```

This config works, but I need to know which `Require` directive passed. My final goal is to set some custom header like `X-Auth-Rule` to different values, like `Regular`, `Manager` or `Admin`.

Is there a way to do this?

p.s. Before someone suggests this, I know I could get the sAMAccountName and query the LDAP myself, from the proxied app, but I'm seeking for alternatives to this.